# How to get previous month's number

Tags: ssis, expressionbuilder

I have the following SSIS expression:

```
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()),2)
```

which gives me `0614`.

How can I change the month code so it always gives me the previous month's number?

Comment: Are you sure this is SSRS? I think you meant to tag SSIS rather than SSRS.  This is a valid expression in Integration Services, which is where you can find Expression Builder dialogue.

Comment: No it is SSRS Expression Builder.

Comment: Opppps... you are right, it is SSIS package :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have no idea what your expression is - it looks like a mix of SQL and SSRS VBA. It may be SSIS as @mmarie suggests.

So I'll give you two answers - SQL (which you can use in the query expression in SSRS) and the actual VBA SSRS expression.

To adjust what you have to SQL to get the previous month, you would use:

```
Right('0' + CAST(DatePart(mm, DateAdd(mm, -1, getdate())) AS VARCHAR), 2) 
+ RIGHT('0' + CAST(DatePart(yy, DateAdd(mm, -1, getdate())) AS VARCHAR), 2)
```

To have this as a SSRS expression, you would use:

```
=Right("0" & CStr(DatePart(DateInterval.Month, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Today))), 2) 
& Right("0" & CStr(DatePart(DateInterval.Year, DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Today))), 2)
```

To convert your original SSIS expression, you would replace `getdate()` with `DateAdd(mm, -1, getdate())` like so:

```
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m", DateAdd(mm, -1, getdate())), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd(mm, -1, getdate())), 2)
```

Comment: mmarie is right. I just had a long day :)... So those two expression is invalid in the Expression Builder for SSIS